# Setting up unit-test for Vue project with Typescript failed with TypeError: Cannot destructure property `polyfills` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I am trying to add unit test for an existing Vue project with Typescript.
I followed the instruction on vue-test-utils for typescript(https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/zh/guides/using-with-typescript.html). However, when I run the test , I got the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'polyfills' of 'undefined' or 'null'. While processing preset:`

What I have tried:
I tried to reinstall the dependencies of babel such as babel-core. Re-examined the configurations. Not working.

I tried to remove the mounting of the component and the error went away. It seems there are some problems with mounting the component.

Here is the small sample code I tried:

```
//component
<template>
  <div>{{msg}}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
};
</script>


//spec.ts

import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import HelloWorld from '../HelloWorld.vue'

describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {
  test('renders props.msg when passed', () => {
    const msg = 'new message'
    const wrapper = shallowMount(HelloWorld, {
      propsData: { msg }
    })
    expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch(msg)
  })
})
```

I am little confused about the error stack there. Is there anything wrong I could fix it?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by explicitly adding a `babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0` dependency (my project was initially using `babel-core@6.26.3`) and regenerating my `node_modules` directory.

I originally saw both this error and `Plugin 0 specified in ... provided an invalid property of "default"` after following the same guide to try to add Jest to an existing project.

Creating a new Vue project from scratch with both TypeScript and Jest enabled was helpful for seeing that a newer version of Babel was required. See also https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1131.